# Why does S3 sometimes return HTTP 206 when the whole file has been downloaded?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've had my S3 bucket logging into another bucket using [Server Access Log Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) for a while. For the Operation: REST.GET.OBJECT sometimes an [HTTP Status: 206 Partial Content](https://httpstatuses.com/206) is returned because the whole file wasn't downloaded. But I can see in the logs that sometimes when HTTP Status: 206 is returned the whole file was downloaded. I've removed some fields to make it simpler:

- Operation: REST.GET.OBJECT
- Request-URI: "GET [File] HTTP/1.1"
- HTTP Status: 206
- Error Code: -
- Bytes Sent:  76431360
- Object Size: 76431360
- Total Time: 16276
- Turn-Around Time: 190

What happened here? If the Bytes Sent are the same as the Object Size then how can the source report this as a Partial Content?

Answer (score 6):

The 206 status has nothing to do with incomplete file transfer. The server determines what status code to send before it starts sending the response body, so it would have to predict future to know whether it will be able to send the whole file.

Instead, what 206 status code actually means is that the following three things happened at once:

- the client sent `Range` header in its request;
- the server decided to honour it and send exactly the bytes requested, not the whole file;
- the server was actually able to do so — the range was valid and satisfiable.

In this case, the standard requires the server to reply with the 206 status code, not 200, regardless whether the range happen to cover exactly the whole file or only a part of it.

Comment: Seems like AWS doesn't record the range request https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712915#712915